# Из за чего WebMethod возвращает undefined?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Делаю приложение, с использованием `asp.net`.
В случае успешной авторизации необходимо перенаправить пользователя на страницу MyPage. По ходу дела столкнулась с проблемой - возвращаемое из веб-метода значение имеет тип `undefined`.

Вот код самого метода:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string userLogin(string login, string password)
{
    if (Login.LogIn(login, password))
    {
        return "MyPage.aspx";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Login.aspx";
    }
}
```

*JS* функции:

```
function clickLoginButton(){
    if(checkTextField(document.getElementById("login")) && checkTextField(document.getElementById("password"))){
        debugger;
        PageMethods.userLogin(document.getElementById("login").value,document.getElementById("password").value,
        onSucess,onError);

        function onSucess(result){
            window.location=result;
        }

        function onError(){
            alert('Cannot process your request at the moment, please try later.');
        }
    }
}
```

Объясните, с чем это связано и как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас объявлен ScriptManager? Он должен находится на форме до выполняемого скрипта и иметь EnablePageMethods="True" (обязательно) и тэг формы должен иметь runat="server" вот так:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True"></asp:ScriptManager>
... 
</form>
```

Еще есть вариант вызывать при помощи $.ajax по желанию, но нужно jquery или XMLHttpRequest написать.

**Дополнение к ответу:**

Тогда советую создать страничку Test.aspx и поместить в нее вот этот код:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Tests.Test" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doThing() {
        window.PageMethods.UserLogin(document.getElementById("login").value, document.getElementById("password").value, success, error);
        function success(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
        function error() {
            alert.log("error");
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <label for="login">Login</label>
        <input type="text" id="login" />
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="text" id="password" />
        <input type="button" onclick="doThing();" value="Go" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Затем поместить вот этот веб-метод в Test.aspx.cs

```
using System.Web.Services;

namespace Tests
{
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public static string UserLogin(string login, string password)
        {
            return "Login" + " " + login + " Password " + password;
        }
    }
}
```

Проверьте, работает ли кнопка на страничке тест. Реализуйте нечто похожее в Вашей страничке.

Comment: ScriptManager объявлен в самом начале формы, EnablePageMethods="True" тоже есть.

Comment: В представленном Вами коде не вижу ошибок, попробуйте мой дополненный ответ, он должен помочь выявить проблему.

Comment: Ваш пример работает, да и у меня на других страницах никаких проблем с веб-методами не возникало, только на этой.

Answer (score -1):

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Это прописано? Коллеги пишут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242334/pagemethods-is-not-defined-in-aspx-page

Вообще, в гугле много информации

```
function OnError(error) {
    alert(error);
}
```

ЗЫ: я бы добавил теги ajaxtoolkit или pagemethods :)

Comment: Пробовала это прописывать, не помогло, советы по ссылке, к сожалению, тоже.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.